# how to switch power between a solar panel and an external 9 V Lithium battery

Tags: power, switching

For my project, I need to switch the power from my solar panel to  a 9 V battery when there is no sufficient sun light powering up the solar panel.

Comment: Great; what are your thoughts so far?

Comment: What is the voltage rating of your solar panel?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a PV panel of Voc=10~12V, you can use high current MOSFET High Side switches for very low conduction losses and voltage drop. Expect to choose a MOSFET switch rated for at least 20x your expected current to obtain a low RdsOn.

A comparator with a few % Hysteresis can choose the higher source, but the PV voltage will,oscillate when it switches back and forth from no load to load. So regulation is hard to do.    To optimize stability, you need a current mirror that senses battery current with a 50mV shunt and loads the PV panel when it is not selected, with the same or slightly less current , so that the comparator can decide better which source can supply the load current above 8V.

To complete a good design, one needs all the parameters of load V vs I, PV V-I supply curve and the 9V battery capacity V-I curve over it's useful life.

For low power simple designs this might end up being a zener regulated clamp for OVP and a Series diode OR for supplying the load.